# What is a one line mysql query that can update all body fields of matched nodes?

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I am trying to do a bulk node update that affects 100+ nodes. I want to set each of these node's body field to a specific string. Say I want to affect all content types: "basic page".

Since my sql skills aren't up to par with join statements. I only got this far:

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_value = 'This is my string.' WHERE type = "basic_page" left join node;
```

Answer (score 3):

In drupal 7 it is a bit simpler.
You don't need the join.

```
UPDATE field_data_body
   SET body_value = 'This is my string.'
 WHERE entity_type = 'node'
   AND bundle = 'basic_page';
```

You must clear the drupal cache after updating content directly in the database.

Also, if you are using revisions, note that you have just changed the latest revision without creating a new revision.
This may not matter to you but it's worth noting.

Comment: this works, but it doesnt work if the body field was never set for the node. it just doesnt come up in the query.